# Audio.play() isn't working in latest Chrome. It's bug or am I fool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

```
<audio id="message_notification" preload="auto">
<source src="http://domain/sounds/message_notification.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="http://domain/sounds/message_notification.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="http://domain/sounds/message_notification.aac" type="audio/aac">
</audio>
```

...

```
function verifyMessages(){

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    ifModified: false,
    cache: false,
    url: (domain + pathSeparator + pathToPHP),
    async: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if( parseInt(data) > messagesCounterFromPage ){
                    $("#new_messages_counter").text("Сообщения: " + data); // it's work
                    document.getElementById("message_notification").play(); // it isn't work
                    messagesCounterFromPage = data;
                    }
                }
});

}
```

This works in Firefox and does not work in the latest Chrome. Audio files are small, issue tracker write that bug with playing small files fixed. I still make the file more from 228 kilobytes, but nothing has changed. It's really a bug or am I a fool? In the bug tracker is something similar with autoplay, but not confirmed.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a bug Chrome.
The problem was solved in the file and insert the sound of the "non-working" file in the "work". Specific reason do not know yet.